# How to simulate an Webhook using POSTMAN and receive it in an Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postman

I'm developing a Website (site A) that will receive a call from another website (site B) through Webhook.

The site B will send the following structure:

```
{
    "data": {
        "subscription_id": "F4115E5E28AE4CCA941FCCCCCABE9A0A",
        "status": "pending",
        "id": "1757E1D7FD5E410A9C563024250015BF",
        "account_id": "70CA234077134ED0BF2E0E46B0EDC36F"
    },
    "event": "invoice.created"
}
```

The guide of site B says that this data will send with **content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded** and using a **POST** method.

How could I setup it on POSTMAN?

I'm trying the following:1st configuring the header / content type as show below
[image]

2nd: I configure the body like this:
[image]

and then I click on the submit button and it becomes like this:

[image]

Is this right?

If so, how could I get this on my Action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After using 'raw', there's a dropdown menu next to it, which in it's turn, can be set to JSON. The header of the Post request will be automatically configured.

Comment: Well if that drop down isn't hard to see... here's some internet doubloon for saving my sanity.

Answer (score 1):

Try to choose 'raw' and paste your json data. Keep the content-type header on application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

For me it's working. I have tested with WebApi controller method which receives one complex type parameter (similar to your structure)

[image]